# How to run .bat file in silent mode with parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

Hello i would like run in silent mode .bat file but I have two parameters that I will enter one after the other.
It is possible to run the .bat from the command line with the parameters ?
Thanks for helping

I tried @echo off launcher.bat but i don't now how can i set parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the output to the NUL device.

```
launcher.bat param1 "param 2" > NUL
```